# Apex: Retain records in checkbox during pagination

Tags: pagination, salesforce, wrapper, visualforce, apex

Does anyone here have an idea on how to retain the records that was selected in a checkbox in pagination? I used offset for pagination and a wrapper to handle the records. Thank you!

Comment: Please add sources of your page and controller, it will help to understand better your case

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote extension controller and use next() method for pagination, you can make a list of all the 'selected' items on the current page before moving to the next page and in processAll() just iterate over the list.

For more details check out [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141301/how-do-i-persist-the-data-in-pagination) and [this](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000l0IOQAY) discussions.